# JSON File empty after writing to it twice in nodejs app

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, electron

Building a simple notetaking program where you add notes and they get stored into a JSON file, but whenever I write 2 notes the JSON file is emptied completely. This isn't an issue when I just execute the script using `$ node notes.js` for testing functions, only when I make calls to it from the npm app.

notes.js

```js
const fs = require("fs"); 
let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('notedb.json');
let notes = JSON.parse(rawdata);

// takes in note, adds it to database
function addnote(note) {
    // format item to prepare for json
    var jsonitem = {
        "note": note
    };

    // add item to the end of json file
    notes.push(jsonitem);

    // write the item
    fs.writeFile("notedb.json", JSON.stringify(notes), err => {
        if (err) console.log("error");
    });

    // reload the notes on the website
    shownotes();
}

function shownotes() {
    // put notes into string
    var notestostring;
    for (i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {
        notestostring+= notes[i]["note"]
    }
    
    // add to document
    document.getElementById("note-ul").innerHTML = notestostring;
}
```

notes.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<script type="text/javascript" src="notes.js">

<!-- input with script that makes it submit when enter key is hit -->
<input type="text" onkeydown="add(this);" id="note-input">
<script>
   function add(ele) {
       if (event.keyCode == 13) {
           addnote(ele.value);
           var form = document.getElementById("note-input");
       }
   }
</script>
```

Ill add the first note and it will be added to the JSON file with no problems, then add a second note and the entire file will be empty

(Note: I shortened to code to just include the important elements, ignore syntax mistakes)

Comment: What are you using for `fs` in the browser?

Comment: Sorry, im not using a browser, im using npm and electron (```$ npm start```) to run the program

Comment: Do you get any errors? Instead of `console.log('error')` do `console.log(err)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually gave up the issue and used a CSV file as storage instead. I think it had something to do with asynchronous writing/parsing but as I'm relatively new to javascript I'm not sure how asynchronous handling works.

Comment: Had the same issue with writing and reading the same file within the same script. Only was using jsons as temporary medium before integrating with SQL, so no big deal.